# Change panels color on button click

Tags: c#

How to change panels color on button_click event? Below is code snippet, I want to change color of `panel1` when I click on Clear button.

```
private void buttClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
     txtPntX.Text = "";
     txtPntY.Text = "";

     txtSrtPtX.Text = "";
     txtSrtPtY.Text = "";
     txtEndPtX.Text = "";
     txtEndPtY.Text = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's keeping you from doing it?

```
panel1.BackColor = Colors.Red;
```

Comment: @TaW what do you mean? This "works" every time you execute this line.

Comment: well it changes to red and then it stays red.. (just trying to pull your leg ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change a color every time the `txtSrtPtX` textbox text changes, you need to add an event `TextChanged`:

```
private void txtSrtPtX_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      panel1.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

The panel in your case will change color 6 times:

```
private void buttClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
     txtPntX.Text = ""; //1
     txtPntY.Text = ""; //2    
     txtSrtPtX.Text = ""; //3
     txtSrtPtY.Text = ""; //4 
     txtEndPtX.Text = ""; //5
     txtEndPtY.Text = ""; //6
}
```

Comment: That's correct. At the same time, it does not answer the question because he did not ask for a color change on text change, he explicitely asked for a color change on button click.

Answer (score 0):

Why don´t just use:

```
private void buttClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
     txtPntX.Text = "";
     txtPntY.Text = "";
     txtSrtPtX.Text = "";
     txtSrtPtY.Text = "";
     txtEndPtX.Text = "";
     txtEndPtY.Text = "";
     panel1.BackColor = Color.Red; // < This one
}
```